# Drop down menu anchor tag href is not working

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu. If I click on the drop down menu the `href` is not working. For example the if I click on the "Sub Menu 1" item then the `href` for that is not working. Any idea on this.. Please help me out..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>On click Menu</title>
            <style>

    #primary_nav_wrap {
      margin-top: 15px
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul {
      list-style: none;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul a {
      display: block;
      color: #333;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 32px;
      padding: 0 15px;
      font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul li {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item {
      background: #ddd
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover {
      background: #f6f6f6
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul ul {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      background: #fff;
      padding: 0
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul ul li {
      float: none;
      width: 200px
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul ul a {
      line-height: 120%;
      padding: 10px 15px
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul {
      top: 0;
      left: 100%
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul li > a:focus + ul {
      display: block
    }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
           <h1>Testing menu</h1>
        <div id="primary_nav_wrap">
          <ul>

            <li 
        style="
            background-color: #007DB8;

        "><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Sub Menu 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="https://www.gmail.com">Sub Menu 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>

                    </li>

              </ul>
            </li>
            <li style="
            background-color: #007DB8;


        "><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li style="
            background-color: #007DB8;

        "><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
              <ul>
                <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2 </a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li style="
            background-color: #007DB8;

        "><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu </a>


                  </ul>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that is happening here is a focus issue.

When you click on a "Menu", this menu is focused, and a sub-list appears.
But when you click on a sub-item, you basically blur (focus away) from the original menu, and so the sub-list disappear before the click is registered.

Because the focus/blur events trigger before the click event, you cannot click a sub-item.

Comment: Thanks.. Can u please tell me how to resolve this ? should i use any other instead of Focus here ? Please let me know. Or should i rewrite the code ?